# The project was not built

Tags: java, android, eclipse, project, target

I am unable to resolve the error below.

**"The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. Cannot find the class file for android.content.Context. Fix the build path then try building this project"**

I imported the existing project into eclipse and the above error message was shown. I checked the other solution in this site but no solution worked.

Comment: select project, goto project > clean project & select build after clean

Comment: click on top of tab project and select option clean and build

Answer (score 0):

Go to Windows --> preferences --> Android then check out for version of your workspace and Android SDK you are using. Add external jar files for the correct version of android platform

For instance you are using 2.2 then minimum sdk is 8, then you have to add android 8 platform jar file.

Also check your SDK path just in case where you have located it may be in case you using Windows 7 and you may have put your sdk folder in program file(x 86) for 32 bit.

Comment: Ok just try this few steps:
1. Right Click on the project --> Build Path --> Configure Build Path...
2. In the 'Source' tab, Select the project eg. 'myProject/src' --> Click OK.
3. Right Click on the project --> Android Tools --> Fix Project Properties

Comment: when I right click on the project there is no option of android tools

Comment: hahaha,,, Okes,, Click on windows --> preferences if you cannot see Android that means you need to first get ADT plugin get it installed.

Comment: when i click on windows --> preferences then there is android option but when i right click on the project there is on option of android tools

Comment: just let me know on which OS version your machine is i.e. 32 bit or 64 bit.
Change everything to ur OS version, then firstly uninstalling JDK and eclipse and re-installing to your OS bit version of them and Restart machine.
Eclipse is crappy at times due to its different taste for different kind of development.

Comment: mine is 64 bit version

Comment: i would suggest you to download latest ADT bundle of 64 bit and update it using SDK manager. Your issue seems to be rare due to compatibility among s/w you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Go to build path -> configure build bath.Click on android in left menu bar.choose any android vendor present over there.Click apply and ok.So that , all android related stuff get build.